# Desktop like web apps and JS frameworks?

Tags: javascript

I am still learning javascript and the more i learn the more i ask myself why do i need to learn a js framework like cappuccino, sproutcore, qooxdoo, smartclient etc...? The learning curve for these frameworks is steep, also wouldn't it be better to just make use of JavaScript libraries?

Take note, that my objective is to create desktop like web apps. Thanks in advance for any good view points!

Comment: whata about jQuery? Most web developers (including myself) will argue that jQuery is actually easier (yet more powerful) than regular JavaScript.

Comment: This conversation is based on building desktop like web apps. Most developers i have spoken too have said not to use jquery, mootools, yui for desktop like web apps. Since i don't have the knowledge to debate them, i have to agree with more experienced developers. They have all promoted.......ext.js, sproutcore, qooxdoo, smartclient, javascript mvc, cappuccino etc. My only concern is whether these frameworks are even neccessary if u know html5, javascript and css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desktop apps are built with frameworks that are of the same quality as those from SproutCore, Cappuccino, etc.

If you want to build desktop quality apps with true MVC architecture you can either write your own framework on top of a library, or start with a framework someone else has written. (SproutCore was originally built on top of jQuery for example)

The best part of a true framework is that the build tools can include only the pieces needed to run your app resulting in very small code with rapid load times.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you are still learning Javascript, I would suggest that you continue to work with Javascript, and try out tools like jQuery, and then **depending on the individual application you are working on, evaluate whether you need to use a more full featured desktop style Javascript framework at that time - something that will require a knowledge of jQuery/Prototype/etc to evaluate.**

Answer (score -3):

IMHO, those JS frameworks you mentioned are overrated bloatware.
I would wholeheartedly recommend that you learn JQuery instead.
It is a much more minimallistic and elegant framework.
Also, by the time IE 9 finally ships earlier next year, all the browsers
will be supporting most of the HTML5 standard, including offline storage and
websockets, making such complex frameworks completely unnecesary.

Comment: Good luck creating a desktop-like experience using just jQuery. The jQuery UI framework is still very immature and nowhere near as powerful as say ExtJS.

Comment: I assumed Jquery is just made up of widgets for designers to just plot into their websites? It doesn't seem capable of building a fully, fast  and functional desktop like web app.

Comment: Can you point to a desktop-like web app built using jQuery so it can be compared to samples from the frameworks mentioned in the question?

Comment: jQuery is a DOM&Ajax framework. It's of very limited use in the context of desktop applications.